# Fan not working increasing CPU temperature

Tags: power-management

I have `Dell Vostro 1014` laptop.
I am using `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.
The fan of my laptop is not working anymore and increases the CPU temperature upto 85 degree Celsius.
I followed the solution given on this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/controlling-dell-fan-speeds-temperature-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/).
Now after running `$sensors`, output is

```
anuj@anuj-sharma:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +74.5°C  (crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +72.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +74.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Right Fan:      0 RPM
CPU:          +74.0°C
```

Note the `Right Fan: 0 RPM`
CPU Temperature increases upto 85 degree.
How can I make the fan working ?

By checking using Psensors, it is running at an interval of 4-5 minutes for 1-2 seconds and again stops.

Have Google a lot but didn't get any answer working for me.